# Calculate expected value and variance of a t-student distribution without using density function

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, variance, expected-value, chi-squared

Let $(X_n)_n$ a suite of random variables independent and identically distributed, $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and let $Y_n:= \sum_{j=1}^n X_j ^2 \sim \chi^2_n$ a chi-square random variable with  $n$ degree of freedom,  and let 
\begin{align}
T_n := \sqrt{n} \frac{X_{n+1}}{\sqrt{Y_n}}
\end{align}
I showed that $T_n$ is a Student random variable of parameter $n$.
I have to calculate $\mathbb{E}(T_n)$ and $Var(T_n)$ without using the probability density function of $T_n$.

For the expected value I have that 
\begin{align}
&\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}) = 0 \, , \quad \mathbb{E}(Y_n) = n \\
&\mathbb{E}(T_n) = \sqrt{n} \cdot \mathbb{E} \left( \frac{X}{\sqrt{Y_n}} \right)
\end{align}
but I have some problem to compute the expected value of the ratio $\frac{X}{\sqrt{Y_n}}$.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your definition of t-distribution is not correct.

Comment: Sorry, $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$

Comment: Still incomplete, unless you add independence. That allows you to calculate the expected value and variance you are after.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Sorry again, hope it's correct now

Comment: If $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y_n\sim\chi^2_n$ are independently distributed, then $T_n=\frac{X}{\sqrt{Y_n/n}}\sim t_n$.

Comment: There is a symmetry argument on $X_i$ that means $T_n$ also has a symmetric distribution about $0$ and so either has a mean of $0$ or does not have a mean.

Comment: Like @StubbornAtom I am not convinced that your $T_n$ has a Student's $t$-distribution. For example with $n=1$, I think $T_1$ takes the values $\pm1$ each with probability $\frac12$, which is not a  $t$-distribution.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I already know (showed) that $T_n \sim t_n$. My problem is to compute his expectation and his variance without using the PDF of $T_n$